# What is the best way to test job flow in Spring-Batch?

Tags: java, testing, spring-batch

I've got a complicated batch application, and I want to test that my assumptions about flow are correct.

Here's a much simplified version of what I'm working with:

```
<beans>
  <batch:job id="job1">
    <batch:step id="step1" next="step2">
      <batch:tasklet ref="someTask1"/>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="step2.master">
      <batch:partition partitioner="step2Partitioner"
            step="step2" />
      <batch:next on="*" to="step3" />
      <batch:next on="FAILED" to="step4" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="step3" next="step3">
      <batch:tasklet ref="someTask1"/>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="step4" next="step4">
      <batch:tasklet ref="someTask1"/>
    </batch:step>
  </batch:job>
  <batch:job id="job2">
    <batch:step id="failingStep">
      <batch:tasklet ref="failingTasklet"/>
    </batch:step>
  </batch:job>

  <bean id="step2Partitioner" class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner" scope="step">
    <property name="resources" value="file:${file.test.resources}/*" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="step2" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.job.JobStep">
    <property name="job" ref="job2" />
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Job1 is the job I want to test. I really only want to test the transition of step2.master to step3 or step4.  I don't want to test step1 at all...

However, I want to keep Job1's specification intact, since this test is testing the configuration, not the underlying actions.  I already have acceptance tests to test end-to-end stuff. This example is so I can write targeted tests for small variations without creating seperate end-to-end tests for each edge case.

What I want to test is that when the job inside step2 fails, step2.master will forward me on to step 4 and not step 3.  Is there a good way to test this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can replace step2 with a mock implementation that always fail and use a StepExecutionListener to check whether or not step3 and step4 were called.

There are good examples here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html#endToEndTesting

Comment: But what if step1 is a very complex action that I don't want to test, and there are other complex actions not represented by this example? Basically, I ONLY want to test that an error inside the partitioned job will send me to the correct next step, and not any of the other stuff that's going on.

Comment: You can replace the complex jobs with mock implementations that just provide whatever is needed for the next job (if there are any dependencies). For example, say that step1 reads a db and generates a file in a folder. Replace that with a mock that moves a test file to the output folder.

Comment: So basically I should create a second configuration to verify if another configuration would work... Yes, I can easily verify that "some" configuration works... can I also easily verify that my specific configuration works?

Comment: I would separate your testing into "test that the batch flow works" and "test each step separately". To do test #1, I would replace all the real steps with mocks. To do test #2 I would use Spring Batch Unit test API, launching each step separately.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my brain around this. I think I misread your last comment... Basically, I should mock the CHILDREN of the steps in the job, not the steps themselves, because I can test each of those Tasklets or chunks on their own. Right? EDIT: HAH! The explanation matches.

Answer (score 4):

You can test every step separately.
Example:

```
JobLauncherTestUtil jobLauncherTestUtil = new JobLauncherTestUtil();
jobLauncherTestUtil.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
jobLauncherTestUtil.setJob(job);
jobLauncherTestUtil.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
Map<String, JobParameter> params = Maps.newHashMap();
//determine job params here:
params.put(....);
JobParameters jobParams = new JobParameters(params);
ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
//put something to job context, if you need.
context.put(...);
JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtil.launchStep("stepId",jobParams,context);

Assert.assertEquals("Step stepId failed", ExitStatus.COMPLETED, execution.getExitStatus())
```

I hope it helps.