# How to test the whole flow of a Spring Batch application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring boot + batch application which reads a source CSV file, process it and write to target CSV file, I'm struggling with writing tests that will:
use an input - "simpleFlowInput.csv" and compare the "simpleFlowActual.csv" output with an "simpleFlowExpected.csv" file, i would like to write many of these tests but struggle with the way to do it.

My application contain only one step and one job:

```
@Bean("csvFileToFileStep")
public Step csvFileToFileStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("csvFileToFileStep").<RowInput, RowOutput>chunk(10000).reader(csvRowsReader()).processor(csvRowsProcessor())
            .writer(compositeItemWriter()).build();
}

@Bean("csvFileToCsvJob")
Job csvFileToCsvJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("csvFileToCsvJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener).flow(csvFileToFileStep()).end()
            .build();
}
```

My current test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootTest
public class Tester{

    @Autowired
    Job csvFileToCsvJob;
    @Autowired
    Step csvFileToFileStep;
    @Autowired
    CsvFileReadProcessAndWriteConfig csvFileReadProcessAndWriteConfig;
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();


    @Test
    public void testSimpleFlow() throws Exception {

        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File fileInput = new File(classLoader.getResource("simpleFlowInput.csv").getFile());
        File fileActual = new File(classLoader.getResource("simpleFlowActual.csv").getFile());
        File fileExpected = new File(classLoader.getResource("simpleFlowExpected.csv").getFile());

        FileManager.getInstance().setInputFileLocation(fileInput.toString());
        FileManager.getInstance().setOutputFileLocation(fileActual.toString());

        System.out.println(fileExpected.length());
        System.out.println(fileActual.length());

        Assert.assertTrue(fileExpected.length() == fileActual.length());
        AssertFile.assertFileEquals(fileExpected,fileActual);//compare
    }
}
```

Any advise on how to test it ?

( I found this question written at 2010 with a partial answer mentioning "JobLauncherTestUtils". [What is the best way to test job flow in Spring-Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080735/what-is-the-best-way-to-test-job-flow-in-spring-batch) )

Comment: This article may be helpful: [Testing Spring Batch applications](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/12/testing-spring-batch-applications)

Comment: Thanks Rcordoval, i saw this article as this is one of the first 2 google results for "Spring Batch Testing" but it doesn't help me with finding a solution. it mentions a Gist with this line -         JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
which throws a NullPointerException at my case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [End-To-End Testing of Batch Jobs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/testing.html#endToEndTesting) section of the documentation explains in details how to test a Spring Batch job (including how to use the `JobLauncherTestUtils`).

Spring Batch provides a nice utility class called `AssertFile` in the `spring-batch-test` module which can be helpful in your case: You write the expected file and then assert the actual one (generated by your job) against it. The section [Validating Output Files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/testing.html#validatingOutputFiles) shows how to use this class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: All these examples use JobLauncherTestUtils , i get this: "Could not autowire. No beans of 'JobLauncherTestUtils' type found. Inspection info:Checks autowiring problems in a bean class." every time i try to use it, do you know why ?

Comment: You need to declare a bean of type `JobLauncherTestUtils` in your test context. Here is an example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/test/JobLauncherTestUtilsTests.java#L80-L86. In this example, the job is explicitly set on the jobLauncherTestUtils, but since the job is autowired in `JobLauncherTestUtils` (see its code), you can simply declare the bean like `@Bean public JobLauncherTestUtils testUtils() { return new JobLauncherTestUtils(); }` and your job should be autowired. Hope this helps.

Comment: You can also use the new `@SpringBatchTest` annotation added in v4.1 which **automatically** registers a bean of type `JobLauncherTestUtils` in the test context so you don't have to do it. See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/whatsnew.html#whatsNewTesting

Comment: v4.1 of which repository ? the most recent spring-batch-test that i see is 4.0.1 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-test can't find @SpringBatchTest there.

Comment: you need to use v4.1.0.RC1 for now, v4.1 GA is scheduled for October 26, 2018. You can find the RC version in pivotal's milestone repository: http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-test/4.1.0.RC1/

Comment: Do we have any better article explaining how to test a batch Job ?